# Using python for put_item in dynamodb table with Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Writing my first Lambda funcation to put item with Python

**The problem im having - not getting the input from the registration form ( front end hosted on S3 bucket with static webhost enabled ) to the DynamoDB table**

the Data will be sent with this funcation to the API hosted on AWS

```
const BASE_URL = `API-URL`;

function handleForm() {
    const name = document.querySelector('#name').value;
    const email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
    const phone = document.querySelector('#phone').value;
    const data = {
        name,
        email,
        phone
    }
    console.log(data);
    saveDataToAWS(data);
}

async function saveDataToAWS(data) {
    const result = await axios.post(BASE_URL, data);
    return result.data;
}
```

Im not sure im using AXIOS the right way but lets continue

The Lambda funcation im using now is pretty much this :

```
import json
import boto3

dynamodb=boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table=dynamodb.Table('register')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    table.put_item(
        Item={
            'name'=event['name'],
            'email'=event['email'],
            'phone'=event['phone']
        }
    )
    respone={
        'mes':'Good input !'
    }
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': respone
    }
```

Im pretty much 99% new to writting code in AWS so im sure im doing most of it wrong
Really looking for you help !

Comment: start with printing the `event` to see its structure -- you'll need to probably do some debugging to solve this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'event' attribute has a 'body' parameter that will contain the data in your example:

```
data = json.loads(event["body"])

table.put_item(
        Item={
            'name':data['name'],
            'email':data['email'],
            'phone':data['phone']
        }
    )
```

Remember to check CloudWatch Logs as well, as it will tell you whether the Lambda was invoked in the first place, and if it failed.

More information on the structure of the `event`-attribute can be found here:
https://aws-lambda-for-python-developers.readthedocs.io/en/latest/02_event_and_context/

Comment: hey bret,i changed the code but im getting syntax error in line 11 :

Line 11\n                'name'=data['name'],\n"

Comment: My bad @EyalSolomon, I copy/pasted without checking. I've edited my answer - there should be a `:` to separate the key/values in the Item-dictionary